# How can i fetch required data from a string using php

Tags: php, regex

otpauth://totp/Dropbox:myemail@gmail.com?secret=MYSECRETCODE&issuer=Dropbox

otpauth://totp/myemail@google.com?secret=MYSECRETCODE

otpauth://totp/github.com/MyUsername?issuer=GitHub&secret=MySecret

I need the secret code , email , issuer , label in the variable . I have coded using explode and it can't the 3rd one. Is there any simple way to get the info using regex ?

```
    $data = $request['code'];
    $remove_rules =  substr($data, 15);    

    $que_exp = explode('?',$remove_rules);

    if(array_key_exists(1,$que_exp))
    {
     if (filter_var($que_exp[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email = $que_exp[0];
    } 
    }

    $secret_exp = explode('&',$que_exp[1]);
    $secret  = substr($secret_exp[0], strpos($secret_exp[0], "=") + 1);    

    if(array_key_exists(1,$secret_exp))
    {
    $issuer = substr($secret_exp[1], strpos($secret_exp[1], "=") + 1);  
    } 

    $label_email = explode(':',$que_exp[0]);

     if (!filter_var($label_email[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
         if (!filter_var($label_email[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          return 'data error';
        }  
        $email = $label_email[1]; 
        $label = $label_email[0]; 
     } 
     else
                    $email = $label_email[0]; 

     if(empty($issuer)) {
        if(empty($label))
                $issuer = "Account";
            else
        $issuer = $label;
        }
```

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are doing. $_REQUEST['secret'] should have your variable... Perhaps you need top look at the parse_url function ? eg; var_dump(parse_url($url));

Comment: I am using Laravel . The $_REQUEST['secret'] contain value like 

 otpauth://totp/Dropbox:myemail@gmail.com?secret=MYSECRETCODE&issuer=Dropbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse the URI using http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php and then [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the query key-value pairs. This would be more correct than using regular expressions.

Try this:

```
print_r(parse_url('otpauth://totp/github.com/MyUsername?issuer=GitHub&secret=MySecret'));
```